# Вызвать функцию, когда возникает событие

Tags: события, javascript, функции

Здравствуйте. Короче, такая проблемка:

Есть блок `<div id="main">` а в нем еще много элементом, нужно вызвать функцию, когда возникает событие `onmouseout`.

Делаю так:

```
document.getElementById("main").onmouseout = function () {...}
```

Но беда! Когда я навожу на дочерние элементы блока `main`, то тоже срабатывает это событие.

Как быть? Что бы такой нехорошести не было?

JQuery не предлагайте.

Comment: > Как быть? Что бы такой нехорошести не было?

Передавтаь объект `event` функции, проверять `parentNode` рекурсивно от `event.target` на предмет совпадения с `#main`.

> JQuery не предлагайте.

Зря. jQuery, конечно, выродился в беспомощный-беспощадный репозитарий плагинов, но пользоваться плохим фреймворком экономнее, чем не пользоваться ничем. Да и не сказать что он чем-то мегаплох при **корректном** использовании.

Comment: @Fike, никуда jQuery не выродился, и в общем-то неплохая библиотека (jQuery - не фреймворк) для DOM. То что его использует школота не делает его плохим.

Comment: вообще конечно эта дурацкая пропаганда "jQuery вам не нужен" слегка задолбала уже. В результате пипл все равно не учит js, а запаривается больше. **DOM функции - не js!** и знать их не то чтобы обязательно, если ты не программируешь фреймворк,либу или браузерный движек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а чем вас не устраивает jQuery ? дело в том, что в нативной реализации всплывающих событий всплытие реализовано двумя разными способами. поэтому stopPropagation сработает не всегда, в jQuery они оборачивают событийную модель по-своему, что делает всплытие более определенным. В вашем случае есть вариант

```
function mouseOut(e) {    
    if (this.contains(e.relatedTarget)) return;

}
//для mouseover
function mouseIn(e) {
    if (e.target != this) return;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T5qfW/

Comment: Спасибо большое, так это же абсолютно рабочий пример.

Я пока хочу сам разобраться во всем этом, как работает и т.п.

Я это делаю для себя, и не вижу смысла использовать jquery, а сам  этот фреймворк считаю нужен лишь для того, что бы быстро решать часто возникающие задачи. Использовать его только в целях работы.

Comment: Ну вот как бы вам сказать. Для себя учите сам js, понять асинхронность много полезнее чем методы dom. и еще раз - jQuery - библиотека, не фреймворк. типа есть разница. Про всплытие я кажется немного наврал, там не всплытие а именно mouseout на дочерний элемент (ну так это устроено странно) поэтому при mouseout делаем проверку на элемент внутри контейнера. А вот при mouseover как-раз всплытие.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте onmouseleave вместо onmouseout.
Если возникнет аналогичная проблема с onmouseover - его аналог onmouseenter, но он не пашет в IE, насколько я знаю.